# Special characters are not displayed correctly in the Linux Terminal

Tags: c, character-encoding

I have a file encoded in UTF-8, as it is shown by the following command : 
`file -i D.txt D.txt: text/plain; charset=utf-8`

I just want to display each character one after one, so I have done this :

```
FILE * F_entree = fopen("D.txt", "r");
if (! F_entree) usage("impossible d'ouvrir le fichier d'entrée");

char ligne[TAILLE_MAX];
while (fgets(ligne, TAILLE_MAX, F_entree))
{
    string mot = strtok(strdup(ligne), "\t");

    while (*mot++){printf("%c \n", *mot) ;}     
}
```

But the special characters aren't well displayed (a `<?>` is displayed instead) in the terminal (on Ubuntu 12). I think the problem is that only ASCII code can be stocked in %c, but how can I display those special characters?

And what's the good way to keep those characters in memory (in order to implement a tree index)? (I'm aware that this last question is unclear, don't hesitate to ask for clarifications.)

Comment: Your `while` looks like it should be `if(mot) for(; *mot; ++*mot)` (EDIT: I don't think you want to increment `mot`).

Comment: Yep, indeed, but I wrote it for the example, that's not the point here.

Comment: NO! See the detailed accepted answer below ;)

Comment: Right you are. @mafso: you cannot print only a *part* of a multibyte UTF8 character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work because your code splits up the multi-byte characters into separate ones. As your console *expects* a valid multi-byte code, after seeing a first one, and it does not *receive* the correct codes, you get your `<?>` -- translated freely, "whuh?". It does not receive a correct code because you are stuffing a space and newline in there.

Your console can only correctly interpret UTF8 characters if you send the right codes and in the correct sequence. The algorithm is:

1. Is the next character the start code for a UTF-8 sequence? If not, print it and continue.
2. If it is, print it and print all "next" codes for this character. See [Wikipedia on UTF8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) for the actual encoding; I took a shortcut in my code below.
3. Only then print your space (..?) and newline.

The procedure to recognize the start and length of a UTF8 multibyte character is this:

1. "Regular" (ASCII) characters never have their 7th bit set. Testing against `0x80` is enough to differentiate them from UTF8.
2. Each UTF8 character sequence **starts** with one of the bit patterns `110xxxxx`, `1110xxxx`, `11110xxx`, `111110xx`, or `1111110x`. Every unique bit pattern has an associated number of extra bytes. The first one, for example, expects **one** additional byte. The `xxx` bits are combined with bits from the next byte(s) to form a 16-bit or longer Unicode character. (After all, that is what UTF8 is all about.)
3. Each **next** byte -- no matter how many! -- has the bit pattern `10xxxxxx`. Important: *none* of the previous patterns start with this code!

Therefore, as soon as you see *any* UTF8 character, you can immediately display it *and* all 'next' codes, as long as they start with the bit pattern `10......`. This can be tested efficiently with a bit-mask: `value & 0xc0`, and the result should be `0x80`. Any other value means it's not a 'next' byte anymore, so you're done then.

All of this only works if your source file is **valid UTF8**. If you get to see some strange output, it most likely is not. If you need to check the input file for validity, you *do* need to implement the entire table in the Wikipedia page, and check if each `110xxxxx` byte is in fact followed by a single `10xxxxxx` byte, and so on. The pattern `10xxxxxx` appearing on itself would indicate an error.

A definitive must-read is Joel Spolsky's [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). See also [UTF-8 and Unicode FAQ for Unix/Linux](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html) for more background information.

---

My code below addresses a few other issues with yours. I've used English variable names (see Meta Stackoverflow ["Foreign variable names etc. in code"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254734/foreign-variable-names-etc-in-code)). It appears to me `strdup` is not necessary. Also, `string` is a C++ expression.

My code does not "fix" or handle anything beyond the UTF-8 printing. Because of your use of `strtok`, the code only prints the text before the first `\t` Tab character on each line in your input file. I assume you know what you are doing there ;-)

**Add.:** Ah, forgot to address Q2, "what's the good way to keep those characters in memory". UTF8 is designed to be maximally compatible with C-type `char` strings. You can safely store them as such. You don't need to do anything special to print them on an UTF8-aware console -- well, except when you are doing stuff as you do here, printing them as separate characters. `printf` ought to work just fine for whole words.

If you need UTF8-aware equivalents of `strcmp`, `strchr`, and `strlen`, you can roll your own code (see the Wikipedia link above) or find yourself a good pre-made library. (I left out `strcpy` intentionally!)

```
#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 1024

int main (void)
{
    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH], *word;

    FILE *entry_file = fopen("D.txt", "r");

    if (!entry_file)
    {
        printf ("not possible to open entry_file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    while (fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, entry_file))
    {
        word = strtok(line, "\t");

        while (*word)
        {
            /* print UTF8 encoded characters as a single entity */
            if (*word & 0x80)
            {
                do
                {
                    printf("%c", *word);
                    word++;
                } while ((*word & 0xc0) == 0x80);
                printf ("\n");
            } else
            {
                /* print low ASCII characters as-is */
                printf("%c \n", *word);
                word++;
            }
        }     
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your very good answer! For the string, I know, I didn't notice it here but I defined `typedef char * string`. I Know what I am doing with `strtok`, you assumed well ;) I note for my next posts for the foreign variables ;) And finally, I don't fully understand those lines : `*word & 0x80` and `(*word & 0xc0) == 0x80`, can you please explain me a bit?

Comment: Actually, I understand the first, it's to know if the character code is less than 128, but I'm not sure to understand well the second ;)

Comment: There you go, added some extra information. And *do* read the must-reads. It's not too dry, Joel's is a pretty entertaining article to start with.

Comment: Perfect, I read the must-reads and your edit, and I totally got it, thanks a lot for this very good answer!